# print String array in Dynamically in my layout

Tags: android, arrays, string

Hi I am developing one app, where I want to print string dynamically in my card view one by one.I want to print each text at next line

so I want to print text one by one, please help me to print text dynamically

Comment: do you want to print your text in every new card view or in one cardview ?

Comment: one text to one textview or multiple text in one textview ?

Answer (score 0):

Its because setText() will replace the existing buffer. You need to use append():

```
tv.append(yourText);
```

append() will append the specified text slice to the TextView's display buffer

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want to create textview dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may be help to you

```
    String str_array="";
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {

        str_array+="i= "+i+"<br/>";


    }
    tt.setText(Html.fromHtml(str_array));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create dynamic view with dynamic text do something like :

You have to create your dynamic layout in the for loop and after that you have to add the view to your container view.

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.temp);


    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflate_specification, null,false);
        TextView tt=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.speci);

        tt.setText("i= "+i);

        conatiner.addView(view);
    }
```

Comment: try that your container is a linearlayout with vertical orientation

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/temp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

Comment: thats your cardview with the container

Comment: in that container you have to add your inflated view dynamically

Comment: which image do you mean ?